# Node Express - PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large

Tags: node.js, express

I got the following error when I try to upload a file(.docx, .xlsx, etc.) higher than 1M

```
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
at readStream (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
at getRawBody (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
at read (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
    ...
```

the code is following

```
...

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var express = require("express");
var app = require('./app');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "50mb" }))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit: 50000 }))

//3.
var user_mng = 'user';
var pass_mng = 'pass';

//server
var port = process.env.PORT || 9090;
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://hostname:0101/dbname`, 
    {
        auth: { "authSource": "user" },
        user: user_mng,
        pass: pass_mng,
        useMongoClient: true})
    .then(()=>{
        const server = app.listen(port, () => {
            const host_srv = server.address().address;
            const port_srv = server.address().port;
        });
    })
    .catch(err=> console.log(err));
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
...
"body-parser": "^1.19.0",
"express": "^4.17.1",
...
}
```

So I tried some solutions, but these didn't work for me.

this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '50mb'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: '50mb', extended: true}));
```

this

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: "50mb"}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({limit: "50mb", extended: true, parameterLimit:50000}));
```

And this:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({limit:1024*1024*20, type:'application/json'}));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true,limit:1024*1024*20,type:'application/x-www-form-urlencoding' }));
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace your 2 lines of `app.use` code to this:

```
app.use(express.json({limit: '25mb'}));
app.use(express.urlencoded({limit: '25mb', extended: true}));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it doesn't work for me

Comment: Can you share your entire script?

Comment: PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large
   at readStream (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:155:17)
   at getRawBody (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:108:12)
   at read (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:77:3)
   at urlencodedParser (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:116:5)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Comment: at trim_prefix (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
 at C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
at next (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
at expressInit (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\middleware\init.js:40:5)

Comment: at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\GoTor\Documents\Node\BackEnd\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)

Comment: I can't post it complete

Comment: Not the errors. I was asking for the codebase. And, no need to post on the comment box. You can just edit your post and paste there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with node or express it's with the nginx.
I'm using aws ebs to manage my application.
to solve the issue you just need to make a file in **/.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf** with the content

```
client_max_body_size 100M;
```